# Querying counts from large datasets using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following relationships:

A Job has many Roles.

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
}
```

A Role has many Shifts and Assignments through shifts.

```
public function shifts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Shift::class);
}

public function assignments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class, Shift::class);
}
```

A Shift has many Assignments.

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Assignment::class);
}
```

I need to get a count of all assignments with a certain status, let's say "Approved". These counts are causing my application to go extremely slowly. Here is how I have been doing it:

```
foreach ($job->roles as $role){
    foreach ($role->shifts as $shift) {   
        $pendingCount = $shift->assignments()->whereStatus("Pending")->count();
        $bookedCount = $shift->assignments()->whereIn('status', ["Booked"])->count();
    }
}
```

I am certain that there must be a better, faster way. Some of these queries are taking upwards of 30+ seconds. There are hundreds of thousands of Assignments, which I know is affecting performance. How can I speed up these queries?

Comment: Have you taken a look at eager loading? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading Use the keyword `with` to load the model with the relationships you want in one query rather than multiple.

Comment: I have looked into it, but I wasn't sure which model should be eager loaded into which in this case. I couldn't eager load shifts into Jobs, could I? There's no relationship there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into the N+1 issue here a few times.  You want to lazy load the nested assignment through jobs then you can access the relation and your `where()` and `whereIn()` calls are executed on the returned collection instead of on the query builder which is why you have to use `where('status', "Pending")` instead of `whereStatus("Pending")` in my example because the collection won't automatically resolve this constraint:

```
$job = Job::with('roles.assignments')->find($jobId);

foreach ($job->roles as $role) {
    $pendingCount = $role->assignments->where('status', "Pending")->count();
    $bookedCount = $role->assignments->whereIn('status', ["Booked"])->count();
}
```

This should be a lot quicker for you.

**UPDATE**

You could even take that one step further and map the result and store the results in a property on the role:

```
$job->roles->map(function($role) {
    $role->pending_count = $role->assignemnts->where('status', "Pending")->count();
    $role->booked_count = $role->assignments->whereIn('status', ["Booked"])->count();
    return $role;
});
```

Comment: Going to look into this, will report back. Thanks!